# Multiplication error in shell script

Tags: shell

I coded this shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR1=`awk -F"#" '/futuro/ { print $1 }' config.conf`
HOST="www.odds.com/matches/soccer/"
ONEDAY=86400
TODAYN=`date +%s`
VAR2= expr $VAR1 \\* $ONEDAY
TODAY=`date -d @$(($TODAYN + $VAR2)) +%Y%m%d`
TOMORROW=`date -d @$(($TODAYN + $ONEDAY)) +%Y%m%d`
FULLTODAY=$HOST$TODAY"/"
FULLTOMORROW=$HOST$TOMORROW"/"
```

... some other stuff

but when I try to execute it, I get this error

riga 8: 1314967172 + : errore di sintassi: atteso un operando (il token di errore è "+ ")

where is the error?

Comment: 7 questions. None accepted. Very good

Comment: Italian error means: `syntax error: operand expected (at token "+ ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
VAR2= expr $VAR1 \\* $ONEDAY
```

to

```
VAR2=$(( VAR1 * ONEDAY ))
```

But, you should be able to say this instead:

```
HOST="www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/"
DAYS=$(awk -F"#" '/futuro/ { print $1 }' config.conf)
TODAY=$(date -d "$DAYS days" +%Y%m%d)
FULLTODAY="${HOST}${TODAY}/"
FULLTOMORROW="${HOST}$(date -d "$TODAY + 1 day" +%Y%m%d)/"
```

Comment: thank you for the cleaner code, but it don't perform the same task completly. FULLTOMORROw must be one day after FULLTODaY and today can be whatever day in the future or in the past.

Comment: HOST="www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/"

DAYS=$(awk -F"#" '/futuro/ { print $1 }' config.conf)

VAR1=$(($DAYS + 1)) 

FULLTODAY="${HOST}$(date -d "$DAYS days" +%Y%m%d)/"

FULLTOMORROW="${HOST}$(date -d "$VAR1 day" +%Y%m%d)/"

Answer (score 1):

`VAR2` is not correctly initialized: its value is `""`. Maybe you forgot backticks.

But you should replace backticks by `$( ... )` construct.

Moreover, `expr` is not the best way to do a multiplication here. Why not use `$(( ... ))` that you already use with additions?

Comment: I can say nothing about `VAR1`: I don't know what is inside `config.conf`.